# Symfony Query Builder add all results in resultset

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am trying to find out all artist list where they have role or not, but my current query just displaying only the artist name who has role in the database:

here is my query:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();



    $entities = $em->getRepository('MyAppBundle:Artist')
        ->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c.id, c.name, c.sex, c.priority, c.bday, c.bmonth, c.byear,IDENTITY(co.content) as work')
        ->addSelect('IDENTITY(co.content) as work, IDENTITY(co.role) as roles')
        ->innerJoin('c.cast_and_crews', 'co')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

    foreach ($entities as &$artist) {
        $role = $em->getRepository('MyAppBundle:Role')
            ->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->select('e.name')
            ->where('e.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $artist['roles'])
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        $artist['role'] = ($role[0]['name']);
```

Also its query timing is very very bad. I have 9000 rows in my table and this query queries all the 9000 rows that I'm seeing from profiler and took more than 1000 ms. Also in this query only one role is show but one artist may have multiple role, how to keep it in the `artis['role']`?

Can anyone suggest a good slution?

Answer (score 0):

Use `leftJoin()` instead of `innerJoin()`.

Assuming that Country entity has many League entities. Also some Countries don't have any Leagues.

**ASSOCIATION**:

```
class Country
{
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *      targetEntity="League",
     *      mappedBy="country",
     *      cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     */
    protected $league;
}

class League
{
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *      targetEntity="Country",
     *      inversedBy="league"
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *      name="country_id",
     *      referencedColumnName="id",
     *      onDelete="CASCADE",
     *      nullable=false
     * )
     */
    protected $country;
}
```

**EXAMPLE QUERY:**

```
public function findAll()
{
    return
        $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('c, l')
            ->leftJoin('c.league', 'l')
            ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
}
```

Example above will return data related from both Country and League so as you can see I'm not running loop like you to select data from other entity because query already returned everything I need.

**RESULTS in your controller:**

As you can see, result includes League as well.

```
$country = $repo->findAll();

foreach ($country as $c) {

    echo $c->getId() . ' -> ' . $c->getName() . PHP_EOL;

    foreach ($c->getLeague() as $l) {
        echo $l->getId() . ' -> ' . $l->getName() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Now you can go ahead and create an **ONLY ONE** query for yourself and like I did above.

I assume yours will be something like this:

```
public function findAll()
{
    return
        $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->select('a, r')
            ->leftJoin('a.role', 'r')
            ->orderBy('a.name', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
}

$artist = $repo->findAll();

foreach ($artist as $a) {

    echo $a->getId() . ' -> ' . $a->getName() . PHP_EOL;

    foreach ($a->getRole() as $r) {
        echo $r->getId() . ' -> ' . $r->getName() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi i tried with left join before your comment and thanks for your answer again but one problem is that f artists has multiple roles i have muliple array for same artist how can i have multiple roles in artist['role'] with just single artist name: here is my code so far

Comment: here is my code :  $entities = $em->getRepository('MyAppBundle:Artist')
            ->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('c.id, c.name, c.sex, c.priority, c.bday, c.bmonth, c.byear')
            ->addSelect('IDENTITY(co.role) as roles')
            ->leftJoin('c.cast_and_crews', 'co')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();

Comment: foreach ($entities as &$artist) {

            if($artist['roles']) {
                $role = $em->getRepository('BbdBongoAppBundle:Role')->find($artist['roles']);
                $artist['role'] = $role->getName();
            } else {
                $artist['role'] ='-';

            }

        }

Comment: Uuuuu..... That's very bad way of doing it! I'll write in answer why. Hang on a bit.

Comment: Just need output like this:

Tom Cruse male Actor,Model (role are comma separated)

Comment: Updated with a basic example. Rest is up to you to modify. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your help, let me think about your flow.. thanks again

Comment: @SamiaRuponti - How are you getting on?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e0ac Hi, Thanks for asking please have a look of my schema so you will understand my problem, I tried with your sample but doesn't help, role is not directly accessible

Comment: As far as I see you don't have direct relationship between artist and role so you'll have to update my example and include other related entities in `select()` and `join()` parts. That should be it.